# Gradle - Argumentos em linha de comando

Tags: android, sdk, gradle, jenkins

Tenho uma duvida sobre como passar na linha de comando um argumento onde irei passar o path do NDK do meu projeto Android.

Eu tenho localmente meu arquivo local.properties onde eu defino o path no ndk.dir, porém existe o problema quando esse projeto vai pro servidor de integração continua, pois não versiono esse arquivo por questões de ser configuração local de cada maquina.

Eu tentei adicionar manualmente no Path do servidor de integração continua, mas não deu certo, dessa forma acredito que passar o Path do NDK como argumento na hora de rodar o script no Jenkins seja a opção mais viável atualmente.

Por isso gostaria de saber se existe essa possibilidade de passar o NDK como argumento na hora de rodar o build do Gradle.

Comment: Já tentou usando propriedades de sistema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução que eu fiz, e acredito ser a mais elegante.

Montei uma task no meu build em que eu crio o arquivo settings.properties utlizando a API de IO do Groovy, busco o path da NDK no SO e verifico se o arquivo já existe ou não. Dessa forma eu faço a chamada no jenkins pra essa task e ele manda rodar.